# Linux/SSH command to delete every filepath found in file

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file full of filepaths relative to its own path:

```
./Talent/152/Resume/a file name.pdf
./Talent/153/Resume/some file name.pdf
./Talent/154/Resume/yet another file name.pdf
... and so on ...
```

What would be the appropriate shell command to go through each line in this file and remove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
xargs -d '\n' rm < listoffiles.txt
```

Comment: +1 very handy to know... i was unaware of the `-d` option for `xargs`...

Answer (score 1):

```
xargs -I{} --arg-file=file rm "{}"
```

or

```
xargs -I{} -a file rm "{}"
```

The quotes protect filenames with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a Bash shell you can do :

```
find ./Talent/*/Resume/* -exec rm {} \;
```

or if you want to delete the files older than 7 day you can add -mtime param like this :

```
find ./Talent/*/Resume/* -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
```